# Issue regards border radius-IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I am using http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/, but it doesn't work for me in IE 8 (normal border also not displayed).  Please help me recover from this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.press_box').corner('round 15px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

IE has issues with border radius, especially (for future reference) if you want a gradient. 
Worst case scenarios is to put a div around the object that has a border radius and setting overflow to hidden

Hope it helps

edit:`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Comment: Okay, the only way I could get round corners was discarding your jquery method completely and resorting to css. See this fiddle for the exact solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8qN6/2/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com).
Download it and inlcude javascript in your page with `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="PIE.js"><script/><![endif]-->`.
After, use this code to fix corners in older browsers:

```
// If IE <= 8
if (window.PIE) {
    PIE.attach('.press_box');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not has sense, forget it because it is only for render, not for capabilities:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

CSS3 Pie could be a solution but I prefer to use it with PIE.htc instead of PIE.js.

See this: [Alternatives link](http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/).

But please, can you show more about your problem? How is your code?
Otherwise we can´t help you.